# Assign consecutive numbers to sequences of consecutive numbers

Tags: r

My intention is to add a vector to a data frame which includes consecutive numbers corresponding to sequences of consecutive numbers in another vector.

For example, in the data frame below, I would like to add automatically a vector V11 which holds consecutive numbers, one for each sequence of consecutive numbers in V1. In other words, I would like to add a vector V11 with consecutive numbers, one number for each sentence in V2.

```
   V1      V2 V3   V4  V5 V6 V7    V8 V9 V10   V11
1   1       I  _ PRON PRP  _  2 nsubj  _   _     1
2   2     saw  _ VERB VBD  _  0  ROOT  _   _     1
3   3       a  _  DET  DT  _  4   det  _   _     1
4   4     man  _ NOUN  NN  _  2  dobj  _   _     1
5   5    with  _  ADP  IN  _  4  prep  _   _     1
6   6 glasses  _ NOUN NNS  _  5  pobj  _   _     1
7   7       .  _    .   .  _  2 punct  _   _     1
8   1       I  _ PRON PRP  _  2 nsubj  _   _     2
9   2     saw  _ VERB VBD  _  0  ROOT  _   _     2
10  3       a  _  DET  DT  _  4   det  _   _     2
11  4   woman  _ NOUN  NN  _  2  dobj  _   _     2
12  5       .  _    .   .  _  2 punct  _   _     2
```

I am vaguely guessing that this should be possible using a for-loop but I am not competent to program one.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you. mydata is the name of your data frame

```
mydata$V11=1
j=1
for(i in 2:nrow(mydata))
{
  if(mydata$V1[i]==(mydata$V1[i-1]+1))
    mydata$V11[i]=j
  else
  {
    j=j+1
    mydata$V11[i]=j
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution would be

```
cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(df1$V1) < 0))
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
```